# MySQL Many-to-Many Pivot Query Throwing Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to build a custom query (I'm using Laravel 5.2 but have no idea how to use Eloquent to build the query I need) that calculates distance and includes a pivot table to return results. I had the query working without the pivot table but when I tried to include it with a JOIN it began throwing an error.

This is the error that I see:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE category_special.category_id = 107 HAVING distance < 22' at line 1
```

This is the query I have right now that is throwing the above error:

```
SELECT
    vendors.id AS vendor_id, 
    vendors.name AS vendor_name, 
    vendors.address, 
    vendors.city, 
    vendors.state, 
    vendors.zip, 
    vendors.latitude, 
    vendors.longitude,  
    (
        3959 * acos (
            cos ( radians(33.7835943) )
            * cos( radians( latitude ) )
            * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-111.95311179999999) )
            + sin ( radians(33.7835943) )
            * sin( radians( latitude ) )
        )
    ) AS distance, specials.id AS special_id, specials.name AS special_name, specials.photo 
FROM vendors
    JOIN specials ON vendor_id = specials.vendor_id
    JOIN category_special ON specials.id = category_special.special_id 
    JOIN categories ON categories.id = category_special.category_id
WHERE category_special.category_id = 107 
HAVING distance < 22 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

My table structure is below:

```
vendors (id, name, latitude, longitude)
specials (id, vendor_id, name, description)
categories (id, name)
category_special (category_id, special_id) - pivot table
```

The goal of this particular query is to return all specials that match the desired category_id whose vendor's location is within the desired distance of the person searching. I've tried different combinations of JOIN types but keep getting the syntax error. I even found similar issues from people on here but none of their solutions was able to get past the error. In short, the user will send a POST request containing a category_id, latitude, longitude, and distance to get these results. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you cannot use where on calculated column, but you can achieve it throw DB::select. Please refer this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-store-locations-with-laravel-and-eloquent

Comment: (1) You could get rid of WHERE clause and move the condition to the JOIN as follows `JOIN category_special ON specials.id = category_special.special_id AND category_special.category_id = 107`. Also, (2) with `HAVING` you need to have a `GROUP BY`